# How to close SQLite Connection in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a code the gets data from my server. Every data will be inserted in my local database (SQLite Database) one by one. Every once in a whole I am getting these two errors. My codes below is where the exception are always appearing.

> SQLite.SQLiteException: Busy
>   SQLite.SQLiteException: database is locked

What is/are the cause(s) why I always get these exceptions?

**Update:**
I added **await conn.CloseAsync();** in every end of the code is that correct?

here is my first code, it will inquire to the server if there were updates and if there are updates it will insert or replace(update) the data in my local database:

```
var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
var conn = db.GetConnection();

string apifile = "sync-retailer-outlet-server-update-api.php";
var lastchecked = Preferences.Get("retaileroutletchangelastcheck", String.Empty, "private_prefs");
int count = 0;

var uri = new Uri(string.Format("http://" + domain + "/TBSApp/app_api/" + apifile + "?Host=" + host + "&Database=" + database + "&ContactID=" + contact + "&LastChecked=" + lastchecked, string.Empty));

try
{
    SyncStatus("Getting retailer outlet data from server");

    var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
        {
            var dataresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RetailerGroupData>>(content, settings);
            var datacount = dataresult.Count;

            for (int i = 0; i < datacount; i++)
            {
                SyncStatus("Saving retailer outlet server update to local database (" + (count + 1) + " out of " + dataresult.Count + ")");

                var item = dataresult[i];
                var retailerCode = item.RetailerCode;

                var insertdata = new RetailerGroupTable
                {
                    RetailerCode = retailerCode
                };

                await conn.InsertOrReplaceAsync(insertdata);

                count++;
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Crashes.TrackError(ex);
}

await conn.CloseAsync();
```

Here is the other code that creates the local database table everytime the StartPage is loaded.

```
public async void CreateTableAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var db = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteDB>();
            var conn = db.GetConnection();

            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<UserTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<ContactsTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<ActivityTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<CAFTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<RetailerGroupTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<UserEmailTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<UserLogsTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<SubscriptionTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<ProvinceTable>();
                    await conn.CreateTableAsync<TownTable>();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("Creating table error " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Crashes.TrackError(ex);
            await DisplayAlert("Application Error", "Error:\n\n" + ex.Message.ToString() + "\n\n Please contact your administrator", "Ok");
        }
    }

await conn.CloseAsync();
```

Comment: Busy means another connection has a lock on the database file. 'database is locked' usually means you're trying to do something in the middle of a transaction that isn't allowed then, or that conflicts with an active prepared statement. See https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html#busy and

Comment: @Shawn but I dont know what I am doing that isn't allowed, I used await so that wont happen

Comment: If you are not sharing one connection throughout the application, make sure you are explicitly closing the Sqlite connection when finished with it (i.e. rolling back the transaction in any catch statements when needed and calling Commit / Close in finally statements)

Comment: You could wrap a using statement round that connection, that would make sure its clean

Comment: @SushiHangover how can I close the sqlite connection and where do I put that?

Comment: @BugFinder how can do that?

Comment: @SushiHangover I updated my code I added await conn.CloseAsync(); on the last part of the code is that correct?

Comment: @lootverge we arent here to point to tutorials, you could have googled.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = db.GetConnection())
{
    // Do whatever you want to do with your active connection
}
```

Note that you cannot reuse that connection outside the scope of the using block and have to get a new connection the same way the next time you want to access your database.

Comment: One question. Will I be getting the same error if I only declared the connection once across my app?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description and code, I assume you use async-style inserts and are on different threads and thus an insert is timing out waiting for the lock of a different insert to complete. You can use synchronous inserts to avoid this condition.